# Check which npm package installs lodash dependency

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

I am using webpack to build a production bundle for an application, and `lodash`, although I have not explicitly installed it and it does not exist in my package.json, is being inserted in my `node_modules` folder.

When I run `npm uninstall --save-dev lodash` (which effectively removes the `lodash` folder from `node_modules`), and rerun the build process, my bundle shrinks significantly. I would like to determine which package includes and requires the full lodash library.

How can I determine which of my many npm packages are requiring lodash?

---

Note:

I am using the packages `lodash.debounce` and `lodash.throttle`. But `lodash.throttle` only has a dependency of `lodash.debounce` and `lodash.debounce` does not have any other lodash dependencies.

Comment: But your npm packages are probably requiring lodash for a reason.

Comment: Presumably, but if it has such a large contribution to my production bundle, I might consider removing the package(s) that require it. This is why I would like to know which package(s) are requiring it.

Comment: Well, you said that you are using `debounce` and `throttle`. If you removed lodash entirely, your script does not work anymore, does it?

Comment: These two packages have no other dependencies (per their own package.json files) and my application runs correctly after having uninstall lodash.

Comment: This tools will analysis the dependencies. https://www.npmjs.com/package/depcheck

Comment: Useful tool in that I'm able to see which particular files require which dependencies, but only seems to mention those dependencies that I've included in my package.json (not those that are included in node_modules)

Comment: `npm ls lodash` should show you all the instances of `lodash` in the entire dependency tree.

Comment: You asked exactly the same problem I am having now. In my case, I run `npm ls lodash` and it shows `react-redux@5.0.6`

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for typescript package which is upgrading from 3.5.3 to 3.9.7 implicitly.
With the help of @Kenan I will make contribution:

> When run as ll or la, it shows extended information by default.
> Blockquote
> https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/ls.html

`npm [ls|la|list] [[<@scope>/]<pkg> ...]`

[image]
[image]

In my situation typescript version ^3.5.3 in package.json but it was upgrading to 3.9.7 because of `^` character. npm is intalling this package's latest version of major version 3. Installed version 3.9.7 doesn't match in any typescript dependency in package.json files.